# Linux user starts in wrong directory?

Tags: linux, user-profile

Whenever I su to user X, it always starts in user Y home directory. The biggest issue is that then X doesn't run its .bash_profile, it attempts Y's and fails. I'm guessing it's just a typo in how the user was defined, but don't know where that is. This is on Red Hat.

How do I change the user's starting directory or otherwise fix these symptoms?

Comment: are you doing `su <user>` or `su <user> -` ?

Comment: @Zypher I was just doing su X

Comment: The option below leads me to believe the problem is that I logged in as user Y, and was in his home. Did some stuff from there and was looking to switch to user X with X's full profile. The -l flag provides the behavior I was expecting

Comment: You should mark it answered, then ;)

Comment: I had to wait 10 min. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `su -l $userX` to, "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly."